# .NET RSA encryption not working with OpenSSL

Tags: .net, ssl, encryption, openssl, rsa

I have created a demo repo at https://github.com/eastwood/dotnet-rsa-encryption. From the README, which includes the problem statement.

## RSA Encryption Problem

I have generated a random RSA key pair. This was done using:

```
openssl genrsa -out test-key.pem 4096
openssl rsa -in key.pem -pubout > test-key-public.key
```

The below outlines the problem, where I cannot get a working solution for .NET Core at all.

### Prerequisites

1. dotnet core
2. node js
3. openssl

Commands were run on osx, but hopefully should work for windows + linux too.

### Open SSL CLI

```
$ cat run-cli.sh`

echo "Encrypting the following text: 4111111111111"
echo "411111111111" | openssl rsautl -encrypt -oaep -pubin -inkey certs/test-key-public.key | base64 | cat > cli-encrypted.txt
cat cli-encrypted.txt | base64 --decode | openssl rsautl -decrypt -oaep -inkey certs/test-key.pem
```

This works perfectly as expected.

### Node

Node works fine too. The mockup is [here](https://github.com/eastwood/dotnet-rsa-encryption/blob/master/node.js)

You can run via:

```
npm i
npm run start && ./run-node.sh`
```

### .NET Core

.NET is not working :(

```
class Program
  {
    static void Main()
    {
      using (var rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider())
      {
        var publicKey = "<snipped>";
        var data = "411111111111";
        var rsaKeyInfo = rsa.ExportParameters(false);
        var byteArray = Convert.FromBase64String(publicKey);
        rsaKeyInfo.Modulus = byteArray;
        rsa.ImportParameters(rsaKeyInfo);
        var result = rsa.Encrypt(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data), true);
        var encrypted = Convert.ToBase64String(result);
        Console.WriteLine(encrypted);
        System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"dotnet-encrypted.txt", encrypted);
      }
    }
  }
```

`dotnet run && ./run-dotnet.sh`

The problem is inherently with my .NET (i'm using dotnet core) implementation, whereby I'm able to import a 4096 bit RSA public key and encrypt data correctly. However, upon decrypting with OpenSSL, I get a failure:

> 140735518716872:error:0406506C:rsa routines:RSA_EAY_PRIVATE_DECRYPT:data greater than mod len:/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/libressl/libressl-22.50.2/libressl/crypto/rsa/rsa_eay.c:515

### Attempts

I have tried:

- changing encoding types
- OAEP padding
- removing BOM
- Reversing byte order

I was hoping there are some .NET / RSA specialists out there that have run into this issue before and suggest solutions to the problem

Cheers,

C.

Comment: It appears I've got a working implementation now. Updated the git repo with the details. Just had to use something like BouncyCastle to rip out the correct modulus from the PEM file and process accordingly.

Comment: Good that you've got it working, although you can certainly get it to work without involving Bouncy. You're not handling the public key correctly (a key is not just a modulus) and your `Encrypt` function uses `true` which indicates OAEP encryption instead of PKCS#1 encryption in above code. Please indicate if this question is still valid, otherwise you might want to self-answer or delete it altogether.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up going with bouncy castle implementation, though as Maarten points out there is likely a vanilla solution available.